# Why do I have to supply foreign key property values manually (in this situation)?

Tags: entity-framework, .net-4.0, ef-code-first, entity-framework-5

When I have a model like this...

```
public class Order
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    [Key, Column(Order = 2)]
    public int OrderId { get; set; }

    public ICollection<OrderItem> Items { get; set; }
}

public class OrderItem
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    [Key, Column(Order = 2)]
    public int OrderId { get; set; }
    [Key, Column(Order = 3)]
    public int OrderItemId { get; set; }
}
```

...I don't need to supply the foreign key values `OrderItem.CustomerId` and `OrderItem.OrderId` manually when I add an `Order - OrderItems` graph to the database:

```
var order = new Order
{
    CustomerId = 5,
    OrderId = 1,
    Items = new List<OrderItem>
    {
        // I don't need to set CustomerId and OrderId here
        new OrderItem { OrderItemId = 12 }
    }
};
context.Orders.Add(order);
context.SaveChanges();
```

`SaveChanges` will generate SQL statements to insert the `Order` and the `OrderItem`. For `OrderItem` it is:

```
exec sp_executesql N'insert
[dbo].[OrderItems]([CustomerId], [OrderId], [OrderItemId])
values (@0, @1, @2)
',N'@0 int,@1 int,@2 int',@0=5,@1=1,@2=12
```

So, the FKs `CustomerId` and `OrderId` are correctly set (`@0=5` and `@1=1`).

However, if I add another relationship to a `Customer` entity to the model by just adding a navigation property to `Order`...

```
public Customer Customer { get; set; }
```

...with a `Customer` class like this...

```
public class Customer
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
}
```

...and call the same code like above (assuming that a `Customer` with `CustomerId` = `5` exists in the DB) I get the following SQL:

```
exec sp_executesql N'insert
[dbo].[OrderItems]([CustomerId], [OrderId], [OrderItemId])
values (@0, @1, @2)
',N'@0 int,@1 int,@2 int',@0=0,@1=1,@2=12
```

Almost the same, but the `CustomerId` is `0` in this case (`@0=0`) which results in a foreign key constraint violation for the `Order - OrderItem` relationship. If a `Customer` with `CustomerId` = `0` would exist and this customer had an `Order` with `OrderId` = `1`, no exception would occur and the `OrderItem` would have been added to a wrong order which might be worse than an exception.

The problem can be fixed by setting the `CustomerId` (which is part of the FK) in the new `OrderItem`:

```
Items = new List<OrderItem>
{
    // I don't need to set OrderId here, BUT CustomerId
    new OrderItem { CustomerId = 5, OrderItemId = 12 }
}
```

Or - it can be fixed by attaching the customer with Id `5` to the context (I have no clue why it works then).

**Is there a reasonable explanation why I have to supply the FK (or part of the FK in this example) manually or is this a bug?**

(I have used EF 5.0 with .NET 4.0 for this model.)

Comment: That's pretty weird, I can understand why you would need to set CustomerId it for a *new* customer but it doesn't make a lot of sense that this would change the behavior of how FKs are auto-assigned based on nav properties

Comment: Is there any difference between the generated FK in the database ? this may help http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591583#relationships

Comment: @knaki02: No, the FK from `OrderItem` to `Order` is the same (composite FK with (`CustomerId`,`OrderId`)). Only `CustomerId` will become a second FK from `Order` to `Customer`. The database schema is correct and as expected in both cases.

Answer (score 0):

Your model looks odd to me and I would suspect is causing your confusion.

Based on what I see i'm guessing you have Customers that can have many Orders and each order should have only one of each type of OrderItem but can have many OrderItems.  One order cannot belong to multiple Customers.  One OrderItem can belong to multiple Orders.

If that is true then I think you need a model like;

```
public class Customer
    {
        //Is the key by naming convention or you could use [Key]
        public Guid CustomerId { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Order> Orders { get; set; } 
    }
    public class Order
    {
        //Is the key by naming convention or you could use [Key]     
        public Guid OrderId { get; set; }
        public Guid CustomerId { get; set; } //This doesn't need to be part of the key 
        public Customer Customer { get; set; }
        public ICollection<OrderItem> OrderItems { get; set; } 
    }
    public class OrderItem
    {
        [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
        public Guid OrderItemId { get; set; }
        [Key, Column(Order=1)]
        public Guid OrderId { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Order> Orders { get; set; }
    }
```

Then when you need to query if you need to know OrderItems by Customer then you can do that with Include or with a data projection such as

```
OrderItems.Select(x=>new { 
CustomerId = x.Order.Customer.Id,
//this rest of your properties
});
```

or if you want the entire entity

```
  OrderItems.Include(x=>x.Order.Customer)
```

Comment: That's really not an answer to my question. Imagine a model where every customer has its own sequence of OrderIds. But the business reason for the model is not important for the question. The model in my question is only an example for a model with composite primary keys where a part (`CustomerId`) is a foreign key.